# try-except block unable to handle error from python module

Tags: python, exception, module, try-catch

I am trying to catch an error thrown by the SDSS Marvin package. My code looks like :

```
try:
    statement that throws error at times
except MarvinError:
    pass
```

Once I run the code and it encounters a MarvinError, this is the error message I get :

```
MarvinError: mangaid2plateifu was not able to find a plate-ifu for mangaid=1-153207 either local or remotely.
You can submit this error to Marvin GitHub Issues (https://github.com/sdss/marvin/issues/new).
Fill out a subject and some text describing the error that just occurred.
If able, copy and paste the full traceback information into the issue as well.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-6207c66f0a5a> in <module>
      2   try:
      3     image_prep(mangaid)
----> 4   except MarvinError:
      5     pass

NameError: name 'MarvinError' is not defined
```

As you can see, it raises a MarvinError, yet my program can't seem to figure out that it exists!

Comment: This means another exception was thrown inside your `except`/catch block, namely that `MarvinError` isn't defined

Comment: Add `from marvin.core.exceptions import MarvinError` to the `import` section of your program.